# Trying to send data cross domain on page exit with javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, amazon-sqs, onbeforeunload, onunload

I have a script on multiple domains that are not mine which sends data to an AWS SQS queue on page exit. When I compare the number of times I receive data to the number of times that the script is loaded on the page I show that 57% of time I do not receive data. I'm expecting to not receive data maybe 10 - 20% of the time which would be acceptable. The data is capturing user actions so I can not send any earlier than leaving the page. I'm wondering if I am doing something obviously wrong in my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function addEvent(){
    var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable
    myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
        if(e || window.event){
            pageUnload();
        }
    });
}
addEvent();

function pageUnload(){
    var host = window.location.host;
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    window.parent.data = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < dataArray[i].length; j++){
            window.parent.data += dataArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    var urlString = 'h='+host+'&p='+path+'&'+window.parent.data;
    var url = 'http://www.AWS_SQS_QUEUE.com?Action=SendMessage&MessageBody='+encodeURIComponent(urlString);
    var method = 'HEAD';//Changed from GET to HEAD to avoid Cross Domain blocking in FF
    if (navigator.sendBeacon) {
        navigator.sendBeacon(url, null);    
    }
    else{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        }
        else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        }
        else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        if (!xhr){
            return;
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the third parameter on `xhr.open()` to `false`. This should cause the call to be blocking, preventing the page from closing too fast which stops the request from being made.